# Readonly elements candidate for constraint validation in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, validation, forms

The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#candidate-for-constraint-validation) states:

> A submittable element is a **candidate for constraint validation** except when a condition has **barred the element from constraint validation**. (For example, an element is barred from constraint validation if it is an `object` element.)

validation steps include:

> For each element `field` in `controls`, in tree order, run the following substeps:
>
> 1. If `field` is not a candidate for constraint validation, then move on to the next element.
> 2. Otherwise, if `field` satisfies its constraints, then move on to the next element.
> 3. Otherwise, add `field` to `invalid controls`.

I'm wondering why this code is not working as expected:

```js
'use strict';

alert(document.getElementById('foo').willValidate); // expected: true; true
alert(document.getElementById('bar').willValidate); // expected: true; false
alert(document.getElementById('baz').willValidate); // expected: false; false

alert(document.getElementById('foo').checkValidity()); // expected: false; false
alert(document.getElementById('bar').checkValidity()); // expected: false; true
```

```html
<input type=text required id=foo>
<input type=text required id=bar readonly>
<input type=text required id=baz disabled>
```

Is this a bug in the implementation by the user-agent or is it expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look here: http://www.w3c-test.org/html/semantics/forms/constraints/form-validation-willValidate.html

One of conditions for a `input` of `type='text'` is:

> Must be barred from the constraint validation if it is readonly

FYI: It is assumed that a `readonly` element already contains a value and generally shouldn't need the `required` attribute.